# Are these two ways of including Javascript equivalent?

Tags: javascript, html

There are two simple ways to include Javascript in a HTML document.

Way 1 (script tags):

```
<script> console.log("Hello world") </script>
```

Way 2 (external file):

```
<script src="helloworld.js"> </script>
```

Assuming that `helloworld.js` contains the single line `console.log("Hello world")`, are these inclusions exactly equivalent? If not, what is the difference?

If the contents of the script were more complicated, would the answer to this question change?

Comment: It's equivalent. The browser pauses, loads the file, processes it, and only then continues parsing the HTML. Whether you should use inline code is of course a different story, and if the script is on another server, it might not load or take a long time to load, making the page hang. (edit: not a duplicate of that question imo)

Comment: yes it's equivalent